# jQuery chained/filtered dropdown doesn't work for all selections

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Keep in mind, I don't want to use the Chained.JS or any Django plugins, I've had nothing but issues with them and I've been attempting this for a long time. I really wanted to attempt this myself using jQuery as I feel it shouldn't be too difficult, and previous plugins I had (django smart selects, chained.js) weren't playing well with the other features on my site (and specifically the page this is on).

Here it goes:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#id_carmake").change(function(){
    $("#id_carmodel option").hide();
    var carbrand = $("#id_carmake option:selected").text();
    $("#id_carmodel option:contains('"+ carbrand +"')").show().filter(function(i){
        return $(this).text() === carbrand;}).prop("selected", true);
    });
});
```

This is the code I'm using to make my second dropdown selection based upon the first selection (car make, car model). I believe this is self-explanatory. It actually works! 90% of the time. Most "makes" will populate the second dropdown with their "models".

The second dropdown includes the make name ("Ford F150", "Toyota Prius", etc) so I was able to filter by included text. I am wondering if something is wrong with my code, I am not a JavaScript or jQuery expert, but want to know what I'm doing wrong so I can improve and move past this issue - any help would be appreciated.

I'm using jQuery 3.4.1.

Here's a shortened version of the HTML dropdown if it helps:

```
<select name="carmake" class="select form-control" required="" id="id_carmake"> 
  <option value="" selected="">---------</option> 
  <option value="1">Acura</option> <option value="2">Alfa Romeo</option> 
  <option value="3">AMC</option> 
  <option value="4">Aston Martin</option> 
</select>

<select name="carmodel" class="select form-control" required="" id="id_carmodel"> 
  <option value="" selected="" style="">---------</option> 
  <option value="1" style="display: none;">Acura 2.2CL</option> 
  <option value="2" style="display: none;">Acura 2.3CL</option> 
  <option value="3" style="display: none;">Acura 3.0CL</option> 
</select>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you have multiple options with the same car, you can select only the first one as default using `eq(0)`:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#id_carmake").change(function(){
    $("#id_carmodel option").hide();
    var carbrand = $("#id_carmake option:selected").text();
    $("#id_carmodel option:contains('"+ carbrand +"')").show();
    $("#id_carmodel option:contains('"+ carbrand +"')").eq(0).attr('selected',true);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="carmake" class="select form-control" required="" id="id_carmake"> 
  <option value="" selected="">---------</option> 
  <option value="1">Acura</option> <option value="2">Alfa Romeo</option> 
  <option value="3">AMC</option> 
  <option value="4">Aston Martin</option> 
</select>

<select name="carmodel" class="select form-control" required="" id="id_carmodel"> 
  <option value="" selected="" style="">---------</option> 
  <option value="1" style="display: none;">Acura 2.2CL</option> 
  <option value="2" style="display: none;">Acura 2.3CL</option> 
  <option value="3" style="display: none;">Acura 3.0CL</option> 
  <option value="4" style="display: none;">Aston Martin 2.2CL</option> 
  <option value="5" style="display: none;">Aston Martin 2.3CL</option> 
  <option value="6" style="display: none;">Aston Martin 3.0CL</option> 
</select>
```

Though I will prefer using the ***data-**** attribute. Also, using inline css is not a good practice:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#id_carmake").change(function(){
    $("#id_carmodel option").hide();
    var carbrand = $("#id_carmake option:selected").data('car');
    var matched = $(`#id_carmodel [data-car=${carbrand}]`);
    matched.show();
    matched.eq(0).attr('selected', true);
  });
});
```

```css
#id_carmodel option{
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="carmake" class="select form-control" required="" id="id_carmake"> 
  <option value="" selected="">---------</option> 
  <option value="1" data-car="acura">Acura</option> 
  <option value="2" data-car="alfaRomeo">Alfa Romeo</option> 
  <option value="3" data-car="AMC">AMC</option> 
  <option value="4" data-car="astonMartin">Aston Martin</option> 
</select>

<select name="carmodel" class="select form-control" required="" id="id_carmodel"> 
  <option value="" selected="" style="">---------</option> 
  <option value="1" data-car="acura">Acura 2.2CL</option> 
  <option value="2" data-car="acura">Acura 2.3CL</option> 
  <option value="3" data-car="acura">Acura 3.0CL</option> 
  <option value="4" data-car="astonMartin">Aston Martin 2.2CL</option> 
  <option value="5" data-car="astonMartin">Aston Martin 2.3CL</option> 
  <option value="6" data-car="astonMartin">Aston Martin 3.0CL</option> 
</select>
```

Comment: This actually works well! It pulls up all the models as it should. Before this, whenever I clicked Scion or Toyota and a few other makes, it wouldn't show their results. Now, for those specific problem makes, it shows the first result in Chrome and all results in Firefox. This seems to be a browser compatibility issue? I'll look into. But, please advise if you have any ideas why Chrome won't show all the models for some of these. It makes me scroll down by pressing down key to see the different scion/toyota models in Chrome. trying to explain this as clear as possible.

Comment: @DavidFerrell, *it shows the first result in Chrome and all results in Firefox*....I found the same result in chrome and firefox!!!

Comment: well the example code I provided you works when I run the code snippet in Chrome.. so it must be something else in my code. I think you answered my question though and what I'm dealing with now is something completely different. Thank you for your help, I really appreciate it!

Comment: @DavidFerrell, you are most welcome and best of luck:)